# How to find the input text is from barcode scanner or keyboard in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, barcode-scanner

I have a requirement where I need to scan the barcode with a scanner. After scanning the barcode I get a 13 digit unique barcode number.

Is there any possibility in Android to find from where the user has given the input? Is it from barcode scanner or soft key board?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
int iean=0;

......

inputEan = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputEan);
    inputEan.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(hasFocus){

                iean=0;

            }

        }
    });

inputEan.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

           public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


               iean=s.length();
               //if iean ==  0 it's scanner
               //if iean == 13 it's keyboard
           }

           public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
             int count, int after) {
           }

           public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
             int before, int count) {
           }
          });
```